# get_stylesheet_directory_uri() links to parent instead of child theme on staging site

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help here.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'child2-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts/jquery.js' );
```

This code in my `function.php` links correctly to my child theme's jquery file on my localhost but on the same setup, with database transferred from my localhost, the same code links to the parent theme and the jquery file does not load.

Many thanks in advance!